# pylint false positive for unused argument

Tags: python, pylint

I'm in the process of cleaning up code with pylint in order to be able to use it for pre-commit validation. I have a lot of "unused-argument" warning when in fact they are used. Here is an example triggering a false positive.

```
def addSeven(foo): #Here I have a warning "Unused argument 'foo'"
    foo += [7]

example = [3, 4, 5, 6]

addSeven(example)
print example
```

I do not wish to suppress globally this warning because i would like to see the times when an argument is really unused. Is there an other option that manually adding a disable comment in each occurence?
Is it a known problem with pylint?

Comment: According to http://lists.logilab.org/pipermail/python-projects/2009-March/001800.html, that's because `foo` is not actually used inside the function (apart from being the left operand of `+=`).

Comment: Here, you can change the code to use `extend` instead of `+=`. There may be other such transformations you can perform to eliminate other warnings.

Comment: Ok. That still leaves me to modify each occurence but it's a bit cleaner than using pylint comments

Comment: This is definlity a bug in pylint. The argument *is used*, the problem being that the '+=' operator is not properly handled. You should submit an issue on the pylint tracker (https://bitbucket.org/logilab/pylint/issue) and you may want to disable the message as suggested by @holy-mackerel in the mean time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is reasonable behavior from pylint; if the object passed is immutable then the statement given is essentially a no-op. Only when is mutable does it seem incorrect.

Unfortunately if you don't want to globally disable the warning then you will need to disable it per instance.

Comment: You mean "correct no-op", or just a no-op that pylint is blind about? And instead of staying silent it raises "just in case"? BTW, this is probably a bug from long ago, because now I don't get the warning from pylint when checking examples in this post.

Answer (score 14):

You can disable it for any scope by adding:

```
def myfunc(a):
    # pylint: disable=W0612,W0613
```

see https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#is-it-possible-to-locally-disable-a-particular-message

Answer (score 4):

pylint is generally a good indicator of bad style. Even when it gives a "false positive", it is probably due to doing things against convention. I am no expert, but I'd say a function that only has a side effect is not optimal. Some people (Robert Martin in Clean Code, for example), go as far as saying all side effects are lies.

I'd recommend (again, I am no expert):

```
def addSeven(foo):
    return foo + [7]

example = [3, 4, 5, 6]

example = addSeven(example)
```

Arguments should be input-only, and output should be via return value. Output arguments are bad practice, as far as I know.